# How to create definition for class level typedef function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Probably a naive `c++` question,

I have a class in a library which has a public `typedef` of a function, which is also an argument to its constructor. I want to be able to call this constructor by creating a definition for this typedef.

In order to simplify the understanding, I have created the sample code below,

```
namespace example {
    class MyClass {

    public: 
        typedef int(*MyFunc)(char c, int x);
        MyClass(MyFunc myFunc) {

        }

        MyClass() {

        }
    };
}


static bool MyFuncDefinition(char c, int x) {
    return 0;
}


int client() {
    example::MyClass *myClassObject = new example::MyClass(MyFuncDefinition);
    return 0;
}
```

Which throws a compiler error,

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'example::MyClass::MyClass(const example::MyClass &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'bool (__cdecl *)(char,int)' to 'example::MyClass::MyFunc'  d:\anoopelias\wspace\ppc3\experiments\test\typedefexample.cpp   24  1   TypeDefTest
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, your function does not respect the provided contract (bool is not an int).

Try as follows:

```
namespace example {
    class MyClass {

    public: 
        typedef int(*MyFunc)(char c, int x);
        MyClass(MyFunc myFunc) {
        }

        MyClass() {
        }
    };
}


static int MyFuncDefinition(char c, int x) {
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    example::MyClass *myClassObject = new example::MyClass(MyFuncDefinition);
    return 0;
}
```